# Git - automatically create distinct files for versions on conflict

Tags: git, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

When Git detects a conflict during merge, the default behaviour is to fill the file with `<<<` `>>>` `===` markers.

This is OK most of the time, but sometimes I'd like to resolve conflicts differently and I'd just like Git to create distinct files:

- original version,
- changed version A,
- changed version B.

How to achieve that?

---

If there's no simple command to create those files in one go (which is somewhat surprising), maybe there is a way to extend Git so that it would do it? A custom `mergetool` or something? Just an idea.

---

### Solution:

I've settled for a variant of [@Karl Bielefeldt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828171/git-automatically-create-distinct-files-for-versions-on-conflict/6878750#6878750):

**savefiles.sh**

```
#!bash
BASE=$1
LOCAL=$2
REMOTE=$3
MERGED=$4

cp "$BASE" "$MERGED.git_BASE"
cp "$LOCAL" "$MERGED.git_LOCAL"
cp "$REMOTE" "$MERGED.git_REMOTE"

# never mark the conflict as merged
exit 1
```

**config**

```
mergetool.savefiles.cmd=/path/to/savefiles.sh $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
mergetool.savefiles.trustexitcode=true
```

Comment: You can check following answer to see the exampel workflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git/3407920#3407920

Comment: I've seen that before, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file called `savefiles.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cp $1 /path/to/BASE
cp $2 /path/to/LOCAL
cp $3 /path/to/REMOTE
```

Execute the following command inside your repository:

```
git config mergetool.savefiles.cmd "/path/to/savefiles.sh \$BASE \$LOCAL \$REMOTE"
```

Add a `--global` if you want to change it for other than this repository.

Then to run this custom mergetool, use:

```
git mergetool --tool=savefiles
```

Comment: Thanks! That's more or less what I wanted- I modified it slightly to automatically choose output file names basing on the content of the `$MERGE` git variable.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go without mergetool, and just display or save the files in the states you mention, the index holds the different states of the conflicted file. You can display (and redirect to a file if you want) with:

```
$ git show :1:file.txt  # the file in a common ancestor of both branches
$ git show :2:file.txt  # the version from HEAD.
$ git show :3:file.txt  # the version from MERGE_HEAD.
```

However, using a graphical merge tool shows you a 3-pane view of the conflicted file. That's usually what people do, so just pick up your favorite tool and see how to link it with `git mergetool` call.

Comment: Also, `git mergetool` opens up the three versions in your editor anyway.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking exactly for this reason- to be able to open the files in my favourite merge tool (namely Eclipse). :) And I don't think I could open a three-way patch editor in Eclipse automatically via command line.

Comment: This solution is troublesome, especially if there are several files with long paths. Maybe it's possible to invent a custom `mergetool` which could do this automatically for me?

Comment: @Kos the egit plugin has merge conflicts resolution with 3-pane view; do you use it? see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Using_Merge_Tool

Comment: @CharlesB nay, I gave up EGit since generally I use Git from console more efficiently (I don't find EGit usable yet, I hope it gets mature soon). In plain Eclipse you can select any 3 files and run `Compare with -> Each other` to obtain a 3-way diff.

Comment: @Kos don't know how you would set merge tool in git to call this Eclipse view, and a quick search didn't find anything relevant, so you'd better go with another mergetool like Kdiff3

Comment: I'm OK with opening the view manually, I just want the files to be created automatically.

Comment: @CharlesB @Josh Lee, I wound up here because of `mergetool` "opening" my editor (kdiff3) with a flag that caused it to automatically (and incorrectly) resolve the conflicts without any interaction from me. So that's an additional use case for just generating the files beyond @Kos's. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

```
git mergetool -y -t bogus <file>
```

Works for me with git 1.7.9.5 / Ubuntu 12.04 and msysgit 1.9.4 / Windows 7 x64.

## Explanation

> I'd just like Git to create distinct files

I was looking for the same thing. Case in point: when invoking `git mergetool -t kdiff3`, git [apparently tries to outsmart me by invoking kdiff3 with a hard-coded `--auto` flag](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-1-3-mergetools-kdiff3-do-not-use-auto-when-diffing-td7585257.html) that instructs kdiff3 to automatically resolve conflicts and exit without showing me the GUI or allowing me to participate in the process ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15813064/1034448)). When that happened and kdiff3 resolved the conflicts wrong, I went looking for this.

When I invoke `mergetool` like so (where `bogus` is a string that is not a valid merge tool identifier [e.g. not in the output of `git mergetool --tool-help` if your version of git has that]), the following happens:

- It reports "Unknown merge tool bogus"
- The index and `file` are untouched
- The following files are generated (where `{num}` is an integer that is the same in all files created by this invocation):

  ```
  file.BACKUP.{num}
  file.BASE.{num}
  file.LOCAL.{num}
  file.REMOTE.{num}
  ```

`file.BACKUP.{num}` is identical to `file`.

### Notes

I think the `-y` should be unnecessary if `mergetool.prompt` is set to `false`. And, according to the documentation, it looks like in newer versions of git `-t` implies `-y`.

The `-t` part can be further shortened, e.g. `-t x` or `-t 0`.

If you have multiple unmerged files, there doesn't appear to be any way to get this to generate these versions for more than one file at a time. E.g. if you have unmerged files `files/file1` and `files/file2`, any of the following will still only generate these versions (backup, base, local, remote) for `file1`:

```
git mergetool -y -t x
git mergetool -y -t x files
git mergetool -y -t x files/file1 files/file2
```

However, if you resolve the conflicts in `file1` and run `git mergetool` again, it'll move on to the next file.